# Enabling IntelliTrace for powershell based Azure deploy

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

How do I enable IntelliTrace when I deploy an azure package from powershell using the command  New-AzureDeployment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grant's blogpost pre-dates VS2012 where we added the powershell controls to IntelliTrace.  (I'm the dev manager for IntelliTrace)  This gives you more options in VS2012.

IntelliTrace is licensed such that you can collect data where ever you want with the new remote collector.  You can only open those files in VS Ultimate however.

First you need to grab the standalone collector:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30665

It will drop a cab folder that contains all the bits you need for collection including PowerShell.

You can now TS into your azure box, copy the bits down and then use these instructions to collect:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh398365.aspx

I've not actually tried to add IntelliTrace with New-AzureDeployment but as the bits inside the cab file are xcopyable, I imagine you just need the IntelliTrace included bits in the package you are 
deploying.  Although this won't turn them on for collecting logs directly from the server explorer in VS.  You would still need to use the powershell commands to control the collection.   To get the control from the server explorer, you would want to do what bhavesh lad suggested.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is supported as IntelliTrace comes only with VS ultimate edition. There are some work around which people has posted but not sure whether it will work... Here is that link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2011/02/20/intellitrace-for-azure-without-visual-studio.aspx